Attempting to write to Sepolia using Forge fails
After running a Forge test against a Sepolia url any changes can't be detected.
But when I run cast command the updates can be verified on Sepolia

cast send 0x171E3C63126f5998A5a588038f3CAC9b2C1E0BEF setTokenPrice(address,uint256) 0x4DE140e6CBbe78FCcBfB44eee2ff14Cc5117Bd1D 99998888 --rpc-url https://sepolia.infura.io/v3/xxxxxxxxxx --private-key xxxxxxxxxx

blockHash               0x5d1f6f2e5e71e2cb269388586bbbbcfb7016c05a7e042295e362c2bf856cca55
blockNumber             6964660
contractAddress         
cumulativeGasUsed       7466007
effectiveGasPrice       877512271
from                    0xb04d6a4949fa623629e0ED6bd4Ecb78A8C847693
gasUsed                 27037
logs                    []
logsBloom               0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
root                    
status                  1 (success)
transactionHash         0x757abb3b68e6f60e6172686a10865a3f4a4c591172a6e9211e3cb3fc60116d96
transactionIndex        45
type                    2
blobGasPrice            
blobGasUsed             
authorizationList       
to                      0x171E3C63126f5998A5a588038f3CAC9b2C1E0BEF

But when I run the Forge test:
forge test --rpc-url https://sepolia.infura.io/v3/xxxxxxxxxx --gas-report --verbosity --match-contract Arbitrage --match-test swapTokens -vvvv
Ran 1 test for test/Arbitrage.t.sol:ArbitrageTest
[PASS] test_swapTokens() (gas: 31600)
Logs:
  Owner Address: 0xb04d6a4949fa623629e0ED6bd4Ecb78A8C847693
  Loaded contract addresses:
  Arbitrage Address: 0xd0257EB082a49B787E2f17C4B2E1e68609f41380
  Router1 Address: 0x171E3C63126f5998A5a588038f3CAC9b2C1E0BEF
  Router2 Address: 0xb8772b6bf319efCA6e98c9c26D63CfDf90ad3434
  Vault Address: 0x900bcBc7a1e516131771E71dE695cbe51F8bF962
  XToken Address: 0x4DE140e6CBbe78FCcBfB44eee2ff14Cc5117Bd1D
  @router1TokenPrice: 120
  @router2TokenPrice: 80
  Setup completed successfully.
  Function Test SwapTokens
  --router1 address: 0x171E3C63126f5998A5a588038f3CAC9b2C1E0BEF
  --router1TokenPrice: 120
  --router2 address: 0xb8772b6bf319efCA6e98c9c26D63CfDf90ad3434
  --router2TokenPrice: 80

Traces:
  [317867] ArbitrageTest::setUp()
    ├─ [0] VM::envAddress("WALLET_ADDRESS") [staticcall]
    │   └─ ← [Return] <env var value>
    ├─ [0] console::log("Owner Address:", 0xb04d6a4949fa623629e0ED6bd4Ecb78A8C847693) [staticcall]
    │   └─ ← [Stop] 
    ├─ [0] VM::envAddress("Arbitrage") [staticcall]
    │   └─ ← [Return] <env var value>
    ├─ [0] VM::envAddress("Router1") [staticcall]
    │   └─ ← [Return] <env var value>
    ├─ [0] VM::envAddress("Router2") [staticcall]
    │   └─ ← [Return] <env var value>
    ├─ [0] VM::envAddress("Vault") [staticcall]
    │   └─ ← [Return] <env var value>
    ├─ [0] VM::envAddress("XToken") [staticcall]
    │   └─ ← [Return] <env var value>
    ├─ [0] console::log("Loaded contract addresses:") [staticcall]
    │   └─ ← [Stop] 
    ├─ [0] console::log("Arbitrage Address:", 0xd0257EB082a49B787E2f17C4B2E1e68609f41380) [staticcall]
    │   └─ ← [Stop] 
    ├─ [0] console::log("Router1 Address:", 0x171E3C63126f5998A5a588038f3CAC9b2C1E0BEF) [staticcall]
    │   └─ ← [Stop] 
    ├─ [0] console::log("Router2 Address:", 0xb8772b6bf319efCA6e98c9c26D63CfDf90ad3434) [staticcall]
    │   └─ ← [Stop] 
    ├─ [0] console::log("Vault Address:", 0x900bcBc7a1e516131771E71dE695cbe51F8bF962) [staticcall]
    │   └─ ← [Stop] 
    ├─ [0] console::log("XToken Address:", 0x4DE140e6CBbe78FCcBfB44eee2ff14Cc5117Bd1D) [staticcall]
    │   └─ ← [Stop] 
    ├─ [0] VM::startPrank(0xb04d6a4949fa623629e0ED6bd4Ecb78A8C847693)
    │   └─ ← [Return] 
    ├─ [46706] 0x4DE140e6CBbe78FCcBfB44eee2ff14Cc5117Bd1D::approve(0x171E3C63126f5998A5a588038f3CAC9b2C1E0BEF, 115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007913129639935 [1.157e77])
    │   ├─ emit Approval(owner: 0xb04d6a4949fa623629e0ED6bd4Ecb78A8C847693, spender: 0x171E3C63126f5998A5a588038f3CAC9b2C1E0BEF, value: 115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007913129639935 [1.157e77])
    │   └─ ← [Return] true
    ├─ [46706] 0x4DE140e6CBbe78FCcBfB44eee2ff14Cc5117Bd1D::approve(0xb8772b6bf319efCA6e98c9c26D63CfDf90ad3434, 115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007913129639935 [1.157e77])
    │   ├─ emit Approval(owner: 0xb04d6a4949fa623629e0ED6bd4Ecb78A8C847693, spender: 0xb8772b6bf319efCA6e98c9c26D63CfDf90ad3434, value: 115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007913129639935 [1.157e77])
    │   └─ ← [Return] true
    ├─ [27001] 0x171E3C63126f5998A5a588038f3CAC9b2C1E0BEF::setTokenPrice(0x4DE140e6CBbe78FCcBfB44eee2ff14Cc5117Bd1D, 120)
    │   └─ ← [Stop] 
    ├─ [44101] 0xb8772b6bf319efCA6e98c9c26D63CfDf90ad3434::setTokenPrice(0x4DE140e6CBbe78FCcBfB44eee2ff14Cc5117Bd1D, 80)
    │   └─ ← [Stop] 
    ├─ [0] VM::stopPrank()
    │   └─ ← [Return] 
    ├─ [594] 0x171E3C63126f5998A5a588038f3CAC9b2C1E0BEF::getTokenPrice(0x4DE140e6CBbe78FCcBfB44eee2ff14Cc5117Bd1D) [staticcall]
    │   └─ ← [Return] 120
    ├─ [594] 0xb8772b6bf319efCA6e98c9c26D63CfDf90ad3434::getTokenPrice(0x4DE140e6CBbe78FCcBfB44eee2ff14Cc5117Bd1D) [staticcall]
    │   └─ ← [Return] 80
    ├─ [0] console::log("@router1TokenPrice:", 120) [staticcall]
    │   └─ ← [Stop] 
    ├─ [0] console::log("@router2TokenPrice:", 80) [staticcall]
    │   └─ ← [Stop] 
    ├─ [0] console::log("Setup completed successfully.") [staticcall]
    │   └─ ← [Stop] 
    └─ ← [Stop] 

  [31600] ArbitrageTest::test_swapTokens()
    ├─ [0] console::log("Function Test SwapTokens") [staticcall]
    │   └─ ← [Stop] 
    ├─ [0] VM::startPrank(0xb04d6a4949fa623629e0ED6bd4Ecb78A8C847693)
    │   └─ ← [Return] 
    ├─ [2594] 0x171E3C63126f5998A5a588038f3CAC9b2C1E0BEF::getTokenPrice(0x4DE140e6CBbe78FCcBfB44eee2ff14Cc5117Bd1D) [staticcall]
    │   └─ ← [Return] 120
    ├─ [0] console::log("--router1 address:", 0x171E3C63126f5998A5a588038f3CAC9b2C1E0BEF) [staticcall]
    │   └─ ← [Stop] 
    ├─ [0] console::log("--router1TokenPrice:", 120) [staticcall]
    │   └─ ← [Stop] 
    ├─ [0] console::log("--router2 address:", 0xb8772b6bf319efCA6e98c9c26D63CfDf90ad3434) [staticcall]
    │   └─ ← [Stop] 
    ├─ [2594] 0xb8772b6bf319efCA6e98c9c26D63CfDf90ad3434::getTokenPrice(0x4DE140e6CBbe78FCcBfB44eee2ff14Cc5117Bd1D) [staticcall]
    │   └─ ← [Return] 80
    ├─ [0] console::log("--router2TokenPrice:", 80) [staticcall]
    │   └─ ← [Stop] 
    └─ ← [Stop] 

Suite result: ok. 1 passed; 0 failed; 0 skipped; finished in 5.45s (298.41µs CPU time)

It looks like the router contract has been updated, but after checking on Sepolia the value is the same as the one set by the cast command.
Based on the trace it appears that Sepolia was updated, but it was not. Checking on the Sepolia url above there has been no update.
After looking at the code below, is there anything wrong?
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8.26;

import {Test} from "../lib/forge-std/src/Test.sol";
import {console} from "../lib/forge-std/src/console.sol";
import {Router} from "../src/Router.sol";
import {XToken} from "../src/XToken.sol";
import {Arbitrage} from "../src/Arbitrage.sol";
import {Vault} from "../src/Vault.sol";

contract ArbitrageTest is Test {
    address public owner;
    Router public router1;
    Router public router2;
    XToken public xToken;
    Arbitrage public arbitrage;
    Vault public vault;
    uint256 public maxTokenSupply = 10 ether;

    function setUp() public {
        // Load addresses from environment variables
        owner = vm.envAddress("WALLET_ADDRESS");
        console.log("Owner Address:", owner);

        arbitrage = Arbitrage(vm.envAddress("Arbitrage"));
        router1 = Router(vm.envAddress("Router1"));
        router2 = Router(vm.envAddress("Router2"));
        vault = Vault(payable(vm.envAddress("Vault")));
        xToken = XToken(vm.envAddress("XToken"));

        console.log("Loaded contract addresses:");
        console.log("Arbitrage Address:", address(arbitrage));
        console.log("Router1 Address:", address(router1));
        console.log("Router2 Address:", address(router2));
        console.log("Vault Address:", address(vault));
        console.log("XToken Address:", address(xToken));

        // Initialize token prices
        initializeTokenPrices();

        // Add liquidity and check balances
        //addLiquidityAndApprovals();

        console.log("Setup completed successfully.");
    }


// Helper function to initialize and verify token prices
    function initializeTokenPrices() internal {
        vm.startPrank(owner);  // Impersonate the correct address
        // Approve routers for xToken transactions
        xToken.approve(address(router1), type(uint256).max);
        xToken.approve(address(router2), type(uint256).max);
        router1.setTokenPrice(address(xToken), 120);
        router2.setTokenPrice(address(xToken), 80);
        vm.stopPrank();

        uint256 router1TokenPrice = router1.getTokenPrice(address(xToken));
        uint256 router2TokenPrice = router2.getTokenPrice(address(xToken));

        require(router1TokenPrice == 120, "Router1 token price mismatch");
        require(router2TokenPrice == 80, "Router2 token price mismatch");

        console.log("@router1TokenPrice:", router1TokenPrice);
        console.log("@router2TokenPrice:", router2TokenPrice);
    }

// Helper function to add liquidity and set approvals
    function addLiquidityAndApprovals() internal {
        xToken.supplyTokenTo(address(this), 5e18);
        uint256 thisBalance = xToken.getTokenBalanceAt(address(this));

        xToken.supplyTokenTo(address(router1), thisBalance / 2);
        uint256 router1Balance = xToken.getTokenBalanceAt(address(router1));

        console.log("Initial token balances:");
        console.log("XToken@thisBalance:", thisBalance);
        console.log("router1Balance:", router1Balance);
    }

    function test_swapTokens()public{
        console.log("Function Test SwapTokens");
        vm.startPrank(owner);
        uint256 router1TokenPrice = router1.getTokenPrice(address(xToken));
        console.log("--router1 address:", address(router1));
        console.log("--router1TokenPrice:", router1TokenPrice);
        console.log("--router2 address:", address(router2));
        uint256 router2TokenPrice = router2.getTokenPrice(address(xToken));
        console.log("--router2TokenPrice:", router2TokenPrice);
    }


You're not seeing any changes in your live contract on Sepolia Etherscan because running forge test doesn’t change values on a live deployed contract, even with --rpc-url set to a live network like Sepolia. Instead, Forge forks the network state locally, creating an isolated environment where any deployments or state changes only affect this simulation and are discarded after the test finishes.
Therefore, during the executing of tests, any contract deployments, state changes, or interactions with contracts are limited to that simulated environment and are discarded after the tests finish. This allows you to test thoroughly without affecting deployed contracts or spending real gas.
Whereas, when cast send command is being executed, it's executing a real transaction spending real gas, therefore reflects the state change in your live contract.
